# Проектирование БД для сайта

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql, структуры-данных, веб-сайт

Основываюсь на [Моноблоки](https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/). В нем в карточку товара - Моноблок LENOVO IdeaCentre 3 24ARE05, черный, включаются его тип (Моноблоки, Ноутбуки и др.), его серийный номер (24ARE05),  и цвет. Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. К чему относится LENOVO IdeaCentre 3 ? В каком из полей таблицы указывается это значение?
2. Серийный номер товара некоторого типа может совпадать с серийным номером товара некоторого другого типа (например, серийный номер моноблока и ноутбука могут совпадать)?
3. Для одного серийного номера могут быть 2 товара с разным цветом? (и надо ли включать цвет в первичный ключ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Я бы выделил производителя, а остальное писал в name товара.
2. не совсем понимаю, почему это вопрос. Вообще, исхожу из того что серийный номер товара уникален (могут различаться только цвета/характиристики)
3. см. п. 2

Описал схему как это может быть. В таблице goods - все уникальные свойства товара (имя, категория, производитель, серийный номер, мб что то еще). goods_s - таблица связей, отображающая все товары с их характеристиками. atributes - соответственно, характеристики в json (для простоты). Но я бы изучил все возможные характеристики и под каждую из них выделил таблицу с возможными вариантами - процессоры/цвета/ОЗУ/диск и тд. И в таблице связей все это связывал бы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а имя исходя из https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/ что из себя представляет?

Comment: @programmworldworld это URL по которому смотрят конкретно моноблоки) То есть функционал таков, что на предыдущей странице где то поставили фильтр 'Только моноблоки', в БД пошел запрос на все товары у которых categories.name = 'Моноблоки'. если расширять на все категории дальше, то нужно более подробно продумывать атрибуты товара, так как в зависимости от категории они меняются

Comment: нет я про имя товара спрашиваю, а не url страницы

Comment: @programmworldworld по Вашему примеру "LENOVO IdeaCentre 3 24ARE05" LENOVO - производитель, IdeaCentre 3 - наименование, 24ARE05 - серийный номер, думаю так)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253991/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2 . (чтобы не громоздить я завел новый вопрос, на этом вопросе и так достаточно информации)

Answer (score 0):

> К чему относится LENOVO IdeaCentre 3 ? В каком из полей таблицы указывается это значение?

Я бы выделила этому поле "name" или "Название"

> Серийный номер товара некоторого типа может совпадать с серийным номером товара некоторого другого типа (например, серийный номер моноблока и ноутбука могут совпадать)?

Здесь конечно нужно делать составной ключ - из двух полей: категория товара + серийный номер

> Для одного серийного номера могут быть 2 товара с разным цветом? (и надо ли включать цвет в первичный ключ)

Когда у вас может быть неограниченное разнообразие (не уникальное) какого-то значения поля в базе - ему нужно указать, что поле может быть не уникальным ( по дефолту не указывать ничего)