# Структура товаров и их характеристики

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, структуры, структуры-данных

Создаю базу данных с [Проектирование БД для сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253565/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0). Необходимо задать индивидуальные характеристики товаров и их значения (таблица `goods_s`, в ответе на вопрос сказано, что goods_s - это таблица связей, но каких непонятно - нуждается в примере с использованием каких-то отдельных характеристик). Для каждого товара задается идентификатор, категория, список индивидуальных характеристик товара и их значений. От категорий зависит список индивидуальных характеристик товара. Как дальше упорядочивать информацию, я не знаю.

1. Каким образом индивидуальные характеристики товаров задаются семантически (каким образом логически описывается структура)?
2. Подскажите какой структурой данных можно задать
   индивидуальные характеристики товаров (приведите пример структуры: имена полей и значения).

Comment: @alexjust поясните ответ на предыдущий вопрос  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253565/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0/1253580#1253580 (что бы не громоздить вопрос - решил вынести в отдельную тему)

Comment: @alexjust Вернее насчет таблицы goods_s и характеристик товаров